# TypeError when calling functions using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am calling the two functions below from a ttkinter   button

```
search_btn = ttk.Button(actions_frame, text = 'SEARCH TERM', command=lambda: get_matches() & choose_image(photo_image, label_text, label_image))
```

and the functions:

```
def get_matches(): # programmed by Ryan Carr, modified me, all mistakes, mine!
        ''' Compares users input to dictionary entries
        '''
        lst = []
        #with open('enciclopedia_nautica.txt', "rb") as en_outfile: #for italian dictionary
        with open('english_french_italian.txt', 'rb') as en_outfile: # full dictionary
        #with open('english_nautical.txt', "rb") as en_outfile: # for bilingual dictionary
            english_dict = pickle.loads(en_outfile.read()) # load dictionary from text
        inp = e.get()
        # Grabs a tuple containing key, value pair from dictionary
        for item in english_dict.items():
            # Look at both the key and value in the tuple
            for value in item:
                if inp in value:
                    # This prevents duplicate entries
                    # For example typing in apple would give two answers.
                    if item[0] not in lst:
                        # If it exists, append the related key to the list
                        lst.append(item[0])

        # If our list of keys is still empty the string wasn't found
        if len(lst) == 0:
            statement = '\nthe term "'"{0}"'" is not in the dictionary\n'.format(inp)
            translation_field.insert(END, statement)

        for item in lst:
            result = "{0} = {1}\n".format(item, english_dict[item])
            translation_field.insert(END,result)


    def choose_image(photo_image, text_lab, image_lab):
            with open('./images/final_image_dict.txt', 'rb') as outfile:
                library = pickle.loads(outfile.read())

            term = e.get()
            if term == "":
                photo_image.config(file="./images/hello_tkinter_cartoon.gif")
                text_lab.config(text="enter search term")
                image_lab.config(image=photo_image)
            else:
                for key, value in library.items():
                    if term.lstrip()  in key:
                        print(value[1])
                        photo_image.config(file=value[1].lstrip())
                        text_lab.config(text=value[0])
                        image_lab.config(image=photo_image)
```

Although the search term is found and displays the translation and also displays the appropriate image, I also get an error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/nautical_glossary/nautical_dict.py", line 186, in <lambda>
    search_btn = ttk.Button(actions_frame, text = 'SEARCH TERM', command=lambda: get_matches() & choose_image(photo_image, label_text, label_image))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

The dictionary is in the format key: value( e.g.'aft':'verso la poppa')  and the image dictionary is in the format key:(caption, image address) e.g.. 'aft':  ('verso la poppa', './images/aft.gif'),
I am not sure why I get the error message and what I should do about this. Suggestions, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

& can mean different things like binary and or set intersection but is not like in shell.

Ugly hack: replace:

```
get_matches() & choose_image(photo_image, label_text, label_image)
```

with:

```
(get_matches() , choose_image(photo_image, label_text, label_image))
```

Best way: create a function:

```
def search(photo_image, label_text, label_image):
    get_matches()
    choose_image(photo_image, label_text, label_image)
```

then call:

```
command=lambda: search(photo_image, label_text, label_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best solution is to create a function specifically for the button, rather than try to squeeze everything into a lambda. That is how the `command` option is designed to work.

This will make your code easier to understand and easier to maintain. `lambda` should really only be used for exceptional situations, not as the normal way to call functions from buttons.

```
search_btn = ttk.Button(actions_frame, text = 'SEARCH TERM', command=on_search)

def on_search():
    get_matches()
    choose_image(photo_image, label_text, label_image)
```

It's not clear where `photo_image`, `label_text` and `label_image` come from (are they global?) so you might need to make some adjustments. The point is, these types of problems are easier to solve if you don't try to cram everything into a lambda statement.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I will need to think it through. I get no response when the search button is clicked. Obviously my mistake. By the way there is one too many parentheses in the choose_image line